# Etiquetas similares "datatables" y "jquery-datatables" con preguntas diferentes

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, desambiguación-etiquetas

Me he dado cuenta que las etiquetas [datatables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables) y [jquery-datatables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables) en su información hacen referencia al mismo plugin de jQuery, siendo la primera con una descripción mas completa e incluyendo ejemplos para el plugin, y la segunda solo una descripción mínima.

Al punto que quiero llegar es que he visto varias preguntas de [datatables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables) que usan para Bases de datos y nada que ver con el plugin de jQuery. Ejemplo: [¿Cómo generar una tabla con distintas columnas cuyos registros se obtienen desde una misma función?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/73182/6635).

También se puede ver en otras etiquetas como en C#. Ejemplo: [¿Cómo obtener los datos de varias filas seleccionada en un GridView?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/72866/6635). Entre otras etiquetas más.

Por lo que veo [datatables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables) es una etiqueta muy general, que no solo se usa en un solo lenguaje o framework. Para mí sería lo mejor respetar la descripción que se tiene en la etiqueta **eliminar todas las preguntas las cuales no estén relacionadas a la descripción, y hacer de jquery-datatables un sinónimo de datatables o viceversa**

**¿Qué consideran ustedes que es lo mejor?**

Comment: Buena pregunta. Para .net debería ser [TAG:datatable] (sin la "s"). También está en rlang el package https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.4 ... No sé que otros usos hay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Datatables](http://datatables.net), es desde hace bastante tiempo un plugin para jQuery que simplifica hacer tablas en una pagina/app web.

#### Voto por hacer [datatables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables) el el tag principal y [jquery-datatables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables) el el tag sinónimo.

Como antecedente, así es en el sitio en ingles ([ver](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datatables/synonyms))

Como @Mariano comentó, [datatable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable) (sin la `s`) se relaciona con .NET y con lenguaje R. No tiene relación con esto, la misma etiqueta dice que el termino es ambiguo y que no hay relación ([ver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable))

Comment: entonces que se haría con las preguntas que no están relacionadas con la etiqueta, porque veo varias preguntas que son con sql y nada que ver con el plugin, seria quitarles la etiqueta?

Comment: @JuankGlezz pienso que si, hay que quitar esa etiqueta de las pregunas y listo. Tambien podríamos editar la guia de uso de la etiqueta avisando de no usar con [sql] y bases de datos en gral.

Comment: ¿Qué hacemos con las preguntas que actualmente tienen la etiqueta [tag:datatables]? ¿Las muevo a [tag:tablas] y luego hago el sinónimo entre [tag:datatables] y [tag:jquery-datatables]? o ¿Les quito la etiqueta?

Comment: @ArtEze Si se crea una etiqueta "tablas" sera ambigua, porque la van a referenciar tanto a _bases de datos_ como a _diseño_ en varios lenguajes, lo mejor es quitar la etiqueta y dejarles la etiqueta a la que mas se acerque (mysql) --> (bases de datos) o (java) --> (JTable) etc.

Comment: @JuankGlezz Lo tendré en cuenta, creo que sería lo mejor.

Comment: Ya está hecho. He puesto la etiqueta [tag:datatables] como etiqueta principal, y [tag:jquery-datatables] como sinónimo. Pero antes de eso, trasladé las 50 preguntas a la etiqueta [tag:tablas]. Me di cuenta de que habían como 30 que correspondían a [tag:datatables], así que les cambié la etiqueta. Entonces ahora en [tag:tablas] quedan 29. Si les quito la etiqueta a todas esas preguntas, [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23994/diferencia-entre-el-bserverside-con-aserverside-y-serverside-de-datatables) se quedaría sin etiquetas. En caso de quitarlas, ¿Qué etiqueta debería tener?

Comment: @ArtEze ahi la edite la pregunta, era sobre... datatables  :) ya se puede eliminar la etiqueta tablas.

Comment: @EmanuelVe Listo.

Answer (score 2):

Dejo un registro limpio de todo lo que se habló y se decidió junto a la comunidad:

#### Etiquetas utilizadas referidas a ~"data tables"

JavaScript / jQuery

- [datatables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables) ... (con su sinónimo [jquery-datatables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables))

Angular

- [angular-datatables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-datatables)

.Net

- [datatable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable) (sin "s")

Java

- *<eliminar>* preferentemente, o en su defecto usar alguna como [jtable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jtable) / tableview.

R

- [data.table](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.table) (con un "." -punto)

SQL

- *<eliminar>* con prejuicio.

Answer (score -1):

Ya he cambiado manualmente las etiquetas de [jquery-datatables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables) para que quede más ordenado.

No creo que [datatables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables) deba ser eliminada, ya que como bien has dicho, esta se refiere a bases de datos, mientras que la otra, a *jQuery*.

He cambiado la descripción de [datatables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables), quedando de la siguiente manera:

> DataTables significa tablas de datos. Se usa principalmente para SQL, C#, Java, o el framework de Javascript, Angular. Esta etiqueta no debe usarse para jQuery DataTables, ya que existe otra etiqueta especial para eso.

Además pasé la explicación que había hacia [jquery-datatables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables).

---

Estaría bueno implementar un sistema que cambie automáticamente el nombre de la etiqueta mientras uno está formulando la pregunta, y no solo cuando la pregunta ya está publicada.

Ver mi otra pregunta respecto a esto:

[Cambiar automáticamente la etiqueta hacia su sinónimo mientras está formulándose una pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2096/cambiar-autom%C3%A1ticamente-la-etiqueta-hacia-su-sin%C3%B3nimo-mientras-est%C3%A1-formul%C3%A1ndose)

Comment: Me parece que deberíamos ver qué opina el resto. Tenerlo de esta forma, ¿No generaría que muchos usuarios que no leen los extractos de etiquetas empiecen a usar [TAG:datatables] en preguntas de jQuery, quedando mal etiquetadas?

Comment: @Mariano Es probable, pero también pienso que antes, al leer la descripción que estaba antes, elegían esa etiqueta en vez de la otra.

Comment: Ojo, `datatables` es el nombre de un producto, no me parece bien que lo hagamos sinonimo de `tablas-de-datos`. No hay relacion. deberia ser sinonimo de `jquery-datatables`.

Comment: @EmanuelVe Pero también [lo usan en Angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52571/como-darle-funcionalidad-a-las-opciones-de-la-tabla-con-angular-datatables)... ¿Es una marca registrada o qué?

Comment: Es una conversion de ese producto a angular. https://datatables.net/ no estoy seguro si es o no una marca registrada. Pero no es muy probable que otro producto tome su nombre.

Comment: @EmanuelVe No sabía eso, es buen dato. Pienso que las preguntas que no tienen relación con el producto, deberían ir en [tag:tablas-de-datos].

Comment: ¡Que diablos es `tablas-de-datos`? o van a ser de `tablas-de-madera` :D? Quiero decir que las tablas ya son de datos, no se si esa etiqueta tiene sentido.

Comment: @EmanuelVe Entonces [tag:tablas], así nomás.

Comment: Si estamos hablando de tablas en SQL, ¿hace falta una etiqueta para eso? Quizás no estoy entendiendo qué uso se le daría, pero me suena a meta etiqueta que no deberíamos utilizar para ese caso

Comment: @Mariano Es para englobar el uso de tablas en varios lenguajes, principalmente C#... Ejemplo: [El arreglo de entrada de tu tabla es demasiado largo, Datatable y C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/58870/13558)