# Cambiar automáticamente la etiqueta hacia su sinónimo mientras está formulándose una pregunta

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

> Esto surgió de una pregunta anterior:
>
> [Etiquetas similares "datatables" y "jquery-datatables" con preguntas diferentes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2094/13558)
>
> ... en la que respondí con lo siguiente:

Estaría bueno implementar un sistema que cambie automáticamente el nombre de la etiqueta mientras uno está formulando la pregunta, y no solo cuando la pregunta ya está publicada.

Los sinónimos serían los siguientes:

> Las de la izquierda, serían las etiquetas maestras.
>
> - [tablas-de-datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tablas-de-datos) ← [datatables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables)
> - [jquery-datatables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables) ← [datatables-jquery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables-jquery)

De esta manera, mientras uno está escribiendo, se entera de que existe [datatables-jquery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables-jquery). Al escribir [datatables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables), y luego presionar un espacio, se dará cuenta de que lo redirecciona a [tablas-de-datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tablas-de-datos), por lo que intentará volver para atrás y escribir [datatables-jquery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables-jquery), y lo terminará redireccionando a [jquery-datatables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables).

Comment: No sé si te entendí bien, pero si haces un "merge" de las etiquetas, eso funciona así. Por ejemplo, si empiezas a escribir "featured" te enseña la principal [meta-tag:destacado].

Comment: @fedorqui No lo había notado... Pero lo que yo digo es que una vez escrito el nombre y quede como etiqueta, lo cambie a la principal.

Comment: Mmmm creo que como está ahora es bastante descriptivo, con el texto "también: X" y sugiriendo Y cuando escribes X y esta es sinónima de Y.

Comment: @fedorqui Hay que ver qué opina el resto.

Comment: `datatables` es el nombre de un producto, no me parece bien que lo hagamos sinonimo de `tablas-de-datos`. No hay relacion. deberia ser sinonimo de `jquery-datatables`.