# ¿Deben fusionarse las etiquetas [datatables] y [datatable]?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Me encontré con que existe una etiqueta [datatables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables) y otra [datatable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable) que hacen referencia al mismo plugin de jquery, como pasó [hace unos años aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2108/3834). Entonces propongo como aquel entonces volver sinónimos estas etiquetas con [datatables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables) como el tag principal. Este es un [ejemplo de uso de la 1er etiqueta con 's'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/406442/3834) y este es [un ejemplo de la otra etiqueta sin la 's'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/402641/3834).

Bueno el párrafo anterior era mi propuesta original, pero al parecer también existen en estas etiquetas preguntas referentes a "tablas de datos" de "bases de datos" y no del plugin de jquery. Entonces ¿Qué se debe hacer? ¿Cómo arreglamos esto?

Comment: Está relacionada a [Habría que hacer \[tabla\] rasa con las etiquetas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4839/193460). Ojo que [hay varias de datatable que son de c#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable+c%23)

Comment: Si, lo se todo esta revuelto.

Comment: Al revisar la pregunta relacionada que has puesto me parece las etiquetas genéricas como tabla, table, datatable y datatables deben eliminarse y deben crearse nuevas etiquetas con apellido, es decir, poner el lenguaje al que pertenecen. Como ejemplos html-tabla, jquery-datatables, c#_datatable, pl/sql_datatable y trasladar las preguntas a su etiqueta correspondiente.

Comment: ¿No hay algún mecanismo en el sitió para hacer una lista negra de nombres etiquetas que no deban crearse por ser genéricas?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Habría que hacer \[tabla\] rasa con las etiquetas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4839/habr%c3%ada-que-hacer-tabla-rasa-con-las-etiquetas)

Comment: como indicaba en la otra pregunta, [tag:datatables] tiene la de jquery como sinónima, por lo que lo suyo sería que la principal fuera [tag:jquery-datatables]. Creo que es más lógico así pues seguimos la tendencia de etiquetas [lenguaje-característica] para hacer más claro su uso.

Comment: @abrahamhs Son 189 preguntas de [tag:datatable] ... Creo que la mejor opción para comenzar sería reetiquetarlas nosotros. O sea, publicar acá en Meta, esperar que no haya objeciones, modificar las 189 preguntas reetiquetando con [tag:datatables] (al menos hasta que se modifique a [tag:jquery-datatables]), con [tag:.net-datatables], alguna otra alternativa o simplemente sacando la etiqueta)